# running a private email server

Tags: python, email

Let's say that our organization has a domain name "ourcloud.org, a server with a given IP address, and every member has an email within our domain. This particular email system has to be able to:

1.receive emails from our members, and send the message to the logic unit, and

2.receive messages from the logic unit and deliver emails to the members.

In addition, this private email server does not have to send emails to other domains and should not accept email from others domains.

How can I design this simple email server using python frameworks? or is there any email program that can be easily configured to do these jobs?

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel, I'm sure that every major mail system can handle this situation. Have a look at Postfix, e.g.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here how to send email in Python :
http://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html

You can also use a mail server like Postfix or something like that there is a lot of tutorial on google